# Install and Configure Ansible on AWS EC2 Redhat Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, configuration, installation, ansible, redhat

I have just started  learning Ansible configuration management tool and I was going through Linux Academy tutorials to run implement ansible commands, everything was good and easy with the linux-academy servers but when I tried to replicate the same in AWS EC2 instance i was unable to locate the "cd /etc/ansible/hosts". I have installed ansible using pip command i.e., "$sudo pip install ansible". I have been tried to resolve the issue but unable to find any proper documentation. The links I tried to install and configure ansible are as follows:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/python-tutorials/linux-tutorial-install-ansible-configuration-management-and-it-automation-tool/

Guide me to configure the ansible hosts path to run the ansible commands and playbooks according to my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu EC2 instance, follow this:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-apt-ubuntu

If you are using Amazon Linux EC2 instance, follow this:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-release-via-yum

Installing via these package managers will create the /etc/ansible/hosts file for you.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install Ansible on EC2 instance [RHEL-8]:

1. `sudo dnf install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm`
2. `sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-rhui-rpms`
3. `dnf install ansible`
4. `ansible --version`

Use `dnf` for faster dependency resolution.

Comment: In future please please format your questions/answers with the help of [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

This another way to install ansible.

```
$ dnf install python-pip
$ pip3 install ansible
```